# Multiple Python-Celery Scripts conflict and doesn't execute

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, celery-task

I have **two** **different** **python** **scripts** in **different directories** that has celery schedulers.

**Script 1:**

```
import requests
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
import subprocess

celery = Celery()
celery.conf.enable_utc = False


@celery.task()
def proxy():
    response = requests.get(url="XYZ")
    proxies = response.text

    paid_proxies = open("paid_proxies.txt", "w+")
    paid_proxies.write(proxies.strip())
    paid_proxies.close()


celery.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "proxy-api": {
        "task": "scheduler1.proxy",
        "schedule": crontab(minute="*/5")
    }
}
```

**Commands that I use for executing it:**

```
celery beat -A scheduler1.celery
celery worker -A scheduler1.celery
```

**Script 2:**

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
import subprocess

celery = Celery()
celery.conf.enable_utc = False


@celery.task()
def daily():
    subprocess.run(["python3", "cross_validation.py"])


celery.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "daily-scraper": {
        "task": "scheduler2.daily",
        "schedule": crontab(day_of_week="*", hour=15, minute=23)
    }
}
```

**Commands that I use for executing it:**

```
celery beat -A scheduler2.celery
celery worker -A scheduler2.celery
```

**The issues is when I execute Script 1, it works perfectly. But when I try to execute Script 2, I get this error as Scheduler2 tries to execute tasks of scheduler1:**

[2019-09-14 15:10:00,127: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'scheduler1.proxy'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
'[[], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (77b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/data_scraping/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 559, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'scheduler1.proxy'

***I tried referring multiple answers but nothing worked.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem that you are seeing is that celery is using the same "broker" in both project 1 and project 2.  In order to use two different celery projects simultaneously, all you have to do is give them different brokers.  You can specify a broker using the [`broker_url` setting](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#broker-settings).

We typically use redis as a broker, so it is very simple to put one project on redis db 0 and the other project on redis db 1.  That said, there is a lot of [thinking that normally goes into which broker to use](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/), and deciding on a broker is outside the scope of this particular question.

Comment: So I don't have to manually create redis DBs,
app.conf.broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
This will automatically take it as DB 0? Am I right?

Comment: That is correct.  redis default configuration gives you databases 0-15.